# Asp.net page unable to read the HttpPost Data when submited from android

Tags: asp.net, android

I'm new in Android programming, and I have try to submit some login data to an. aspx page for verification via POST Method, some how I notice that the .aspx page was unable to read the HttpPost data from my android app. 2 thing I have tried to submit my data to an .asp page, the page able to read the data using the same code, except change the URL in it, and 2nd. I also create a simple html file to submit the data to .aspx page, it seem no problem reading POST Method data, so now I have no clue what is going wrong here.

```
      DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mydomain.com/login.aspx");
      httppost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      List<BasicNameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
      nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("strEmail", username));
      nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("strPassword", password));
      try {
          UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8);
        httppost.setEntity(p_entity);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
        ........
        ........
```

The aspx page bascially do nothing much, it just get the data via Request.Form("strEmail") and Request.Form("strPassword") and compare it against the database then pass back and XML result page. So any one have any idea what is missing there?

Answer (score 0):

there are 4 more nameValuePairs that you need to define.

eventvalidation
viewstate
login.x
login.y

(login x and y might be named differently)

Use something like Tamper Data (Firefox addon) to analyze the form post.